# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Estoy estudiando y practicando PHP. Cree un formulario de login, en el cual el usuario se loguea al ingresar las credenciales.

El siguiente paso es que el usuario recupere su contraseña(actualizar) en el caso de olvidarla. Realizo el código, pero en el momento de hacer la prueba por medio de Get, utilizando el id del usuario en la url http://localhost/devcrayon-tienda/cambiarClave.php?=24 me arroja el siguiente error:

*Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
 **Warning**: Undefined variable $id in*

El cual mi sentencia SQL para actualizar la contraseña se encuentra mal; he consultado en diferentes fuentes en internet y no encuentro una solución clara.

Por eso acudo a ustedes, que tienen experiencia y me guíen.

Tanto el html como php se encuentran un mismo archivo que llame cambiarClave.php

```
<?php
require "php/conex.php";
require "php/sesion.php";

if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    // Leer los datos del usuario
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=".$id;
    $r = mysqli_query($conex, $sql);
    $n = mysqli_num_rows($r);
    if ($n!=1) {
        // No existe el usuario
        header("location;index.php");
    }
}
if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $password1 = $_POST["password"];
    $password2 = $_POST["password2"];
    // verificamos las claves
    if ($password1 == $password2) {
       $password = hash_hmac("sha512", $password1, "keySecret");
       $sql = "UPDATE users SET password_user='".$password."' WHERE id=".$id;
       if (mysqli_query($conex, $sql)) {
        header("location:cambiaClaveGracias.php");
       }else {
        $error = "Error al actualizar la contraseña de acceso";
       }
    }else {
        $error = "Las contraseñas no coinciden";
    }
}
?>

<form action="cambiarClave.php" method="post" class="register">

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="password">Ingresa una contraseña<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="password" class="input-text"  name="password" id="password" />
</p>                                                           

<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
    <label for="password">confirme la contraseña<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input  type="password"  class="input-text" name="password2" id="password2" />
</p>

<p class="form-row">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="register" value="Crear" />
    <a href="login.php" class="btn btn-outline-success">¿Tienes una cuenta?</a>
</p>

<p class="form-row">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
</p>

</form>
```

Agradezco de antemano a la persona que me ayude o explique el fallo que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la url deberia ser **http://localhost/devcrayon-tienda/cambiarClave.php?id=24** y otra cosa, mal invento enviar esa id por **get** peligro de inyeccion. utiliza javascript para enviar por post y en php **bind_param**

Comment: No entiendo mucho, ¿quieres dar al `input` con `name="id"` el mismo valor que recogerías luego en el código php proveniente de **ese mismo `input`** ¿? Otra cosa, o `get` o `post`, verifica según el método del `form`, no hagas verificaciones basadas en varios métodos, creando un código kilométrico y desequilibrado. Y, consejo final: ya no se mandan datos así, hoy día se usa Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para enviar datos del cliente al servidor, evitando esa horrible mezcla de contextos PHP / Javascript, donde además, para que algo sea enviado debes recargar la página cada vez.

Comment: Gracias al responder y por el tiempo. Voy a consultar las sugerencias dadas.